# What should I fill in "path for boot option"?

Tags: windows-7, boot, usb, path

I am really confused about this case. I have a new laptop but no DVD drive. I want to install windows by USB. I have set my USB to bootable, and the problem is, there is no option for BOOT priority from USB. I know I have to create the option first, but I was really confused with this. I found these field that must be filled :

1. Add Boot Option
2. Select Filesystem
3. Path for boot option

Especially -> `Path for boot option`, I don't know what to fill. Help me..

Comment: Please explain what you are doing. Where did you find these fields? The boot priority is set in your computer's BIOS, the details on how to access the BIOS depend on your laptop's model.

Comment: @terdon I want to install new windows 7. Yes, the fields was in BIOS. That's the problem, I want to set BOOT priority to USB, but there is no choice for that. My laptop -> ASUS SonicMaster

Comment: What choices do you see? There should be something like boot priority, look for "external" or "usb" or similar or [edit] your question and post the choices you have.